# Compile PHP application to HTML with variations

Tags: javascript, php, gulp, handlebars.js, templating

I have a simple PHP application branded to one company and it contains a few pages. The php pages are then compiled to static HTML using a [Gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php2html) and the HTML files are then deployed to a production server.

I'm now looking to create a variation of this compiled application with new branding. It will just involve changing some of the colours and logo. Ideally I want to use the same codebase so I'm not duplicating code and work effort but just using conditions to replace the logo and stylesheet for each company. Each application should compile in to separate folders to be deployed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Handlebars JS or some other templating tool perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If the application is written in PHP, I recommend [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Extensible, easy-to-use and powerful.

Can be installed with composer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like very simple pipeline. I would recommend you to just write some shell script (or modify existing php script) with arguments (logo path, output directory) to make existing engine produce different output to different directory.

ok, I edited the post, to show the idea.
I was thinking about something like the following:

```
<?php 
    $logo = $argv[1]; //take commandline arguments
    $name = $argv[2];
    $dir = $argv[3];

    mkdir($dir);

    $path = $dir.'/template.html'; 

    $template = '<img src="'.$logo.'" alt="logo"><h1>This is '.$name.'    site</h1>'; //here you could run your templating engine with some names and paths replaced with variables

    file_put_contents($path, $template);
```

Then, you can run this proof of concept script from your commandline like so `php createTemplates.php company1.jpg company1 company1` and you will get `template.html` with company1.jpg logo and company1 headline in `company1` folder.
I have no idea how does your templating engine work or how advanced it is, but for the simple use (few html pages) it should be enough.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea. Can you show me an example?